# Modifying Realm data crashes on tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

You get one thing figured out and something else comes along and that's why I love this stuff.

My workout app uses realm for data persistence and when I modify some of the data elements of the file, it crashes when I reload the tableView. Here is a layout of the tableview in WorkoutViewController.

[image]

I select an item to edit it's three properties (Name, Date and average time).  When selecting Edit the following view controller is presented.  This is WorkoutAlertViewController.

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var workoutItems: Results<Workout>?
    var passedWorkout = Workout()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func editWorkout(workout: Workout, name: String, time: String, date: Date) {
        
        do {
            try self.realm.write {
                
                passedWorkout = workout
                
                print("passedWorkout \(workout)")
                print("changes to be made \(name), \(time), \(date)")
                passedWorkout.name = name
                passedWorkout.time = time
                passedWorkout.dateCreated = date
                
                print("workout changed \(passedWorkout)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error editing workout \(error)")
        }
        
//        loadWorkout()
    }
    

    func loadWorkout() {
        
        workoutItems = realm.objects(Workout.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: false)
        
        print("workoutItems \(String(describing: workoutItems))")
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension WorkoutViewController: PassNewWorkout {

    func didTapAdd(name: String, time: String, date: Date) {
        workoutName = name
        averageTime = time
        creationDate = date
        
        let newWorkout = Workout()
        newWorkout.name = workoutName
        newWorkout.dateCreated = creationDate
        newWorkout.time = averageTime
        
        saveWorkout(workout: newWorkout)

    }
}

extension WorkoutViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workoutItems?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WorkoutCell
        if let workout = workoutItems?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.workoutLabel.text = workout.name
            cell.dateLabel.text = String("Created: \(functions.convertTime(timeToConvert: workout.dateCreated!))")
            cell.timeLabel.text = String("Avg Time: \(workout.time)")
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "No Workouts Added"
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}

extension WorkoutViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "workoutListSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "workoutListSegue" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutListViewController, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                if let workout = workoutItems?[indexPath.row] {
                    destinationVC.selectedWorkout = workout
                    destinationVC.workoutName = workout.name
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, actionPerformed) in
            
            if let _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
                
                self.passedWorkout = self.workoutItems![indexPath.row]
                    
                self.deleteWorkout(workout: self.passedWorkout)
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, actionPerformed) in
                        
                if let _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
                    
                    let alertVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "WorkoutVC") as! WorkoutAlertViewController
                    
                    self.passedWorkout = self.workoutItems![indexPath.row]
                    
                    print("editAction \(self.passedWorkout)")
                    
                    alertVC.didTapEdit(workout: self.passedWorkout)
                    
                    self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

        }
    
        editAction.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
    }
}
```

The app crashes on loadWorkout() with:

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/kevin/Desktop/FitTrax/FitTrax/Controller/Fitness/WorkoutViewController.swift, line 88

Line 88 is tableView.reloadData()

Here is the WorkoutAlertViewController file.

```
protocol PassNewWorkout {
    func didTapAdd(name: String, time: String, date: Date)
}

class WorkoutAlertViewController: UIViewController {

    var workoutName = String()
    var averageTime = String()
    var creationDate = Date()
    var receivedWorkout = Workout()

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        if workoutName == "" {
            workoutName = workoutTextField.text!
            creationDate = datePicker.date
            averageTime = timeTextField.text!
            
            alertDelegate.didTapAdd(name: workoutName, time: averageTime, date: creationDate)
        } else {
            workoutName = workoutTextField.text!
            creationDate = datePicker.date
            averageTime = timeTextField.text!

            let workoutVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! WorkoutViewController
            workoutVC.editWorkout(workout: receivedWorkout, name: workoutName, time: averageTime, date: creationDate)
        }

        
    }
    
    func didTapEdit(workout: Workout) {
        workoutName  = workout.name
        averageTime = workout.time
        creationDate = workout.dateCreated!
        receivedWorkout = workout
    }
}
```

The edit does work without the reload but does not immediately show the changes.  If I go back to the Fitness Menu and back to the Workout Menu, it displays the changes then.  It's something with that reload that I can't figure out.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Look into realm observations my dude. You should basically never use reloadData, not with realm and not otherwise.

Comment: This should be a good place to start; https://academy.realm.io/posts/meetup-jp-simard-mastering-realm-notifications

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @OscarApeland Not sure what you're implying there but using tableView.reloadData is a standard construct to refresh the UI. If you follow MVC or MVVC design fundamentals, the controller controls the UI. The UI has no knowledge of the data or when it's loaded. Perhaps you mean *where the OP is using it* - it should *not* be used within a tableView update as it will cause it to be recursive and overflow the stack. Also that link is 4 years old and a few things have changed - noting that within that tutorial they use `reloadData()` to update the ui when using an observer pattern.

Comment: The crash could be caused by a number of things. 1) It doesn't appear you've loaded the `workoutItems` var so if you attempt to access one of the elements, it will be nil and crash 2) tableView does not appear to be defined anywhere 3) It doesn't appear you told the tableView what it's delegate or dataSource is. Also don't do this `tableView.reloadData()` *inside* a tableView delegate method.

Comment: @Jay paraphrasing from the WWDC talks on UICollectionView, they are pretty clear that reloadData is a last resort solution for updating data. Using basically any other way gives you pretty animations and stuff.

Comment: The talk is old but the core of it remains accurate. ReloadData is obviously correct in some cases, but not in OPs case.

Comment: I updated the question to include the tableview datasource and delegate.  I learned (obviously wrong) to use the reloadData() from online sources.  What should I be using to refresh the tableview after changes?

Comment: @BeKnowDo Feel free to use reload data on your TABLEVIEW (not collectionView) to refresh it when you're not concerned about animations or row-specific updates. It's perfectly fine to load your realm results and the tableView.reloadData() to update the UI. See [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) from the Apple documentation.

Comment: @OscarApeland This is a tableView (UITableView), not a collectionView (UICollectionView), and there are inherent differences in their implementations.

Comment: A few things. That line doesn't appear to be line 88. Also this `return workoutItems?.count ?? 1` is dangerous. Have you asked yourself what happens if workoutItems is nil? Is it? I think you need to do some further troubleshooting; add a breakpoint and step through your code one line at a time - inspect your vars to ensure they are what you expect. When they aren't *that's* where the issue is. Update your question once you've done that. Trying to work backward from a crash is not going to be helpful.

Comment: Oh f i read it on my phone and missed that. Either way I'm pretty sure they recommend using detailed updates over the "hammer" reloadData for either reusable view. The video I linked demonstrates what could be done instead.